# GWT - why I can't get JSON via HTTP?

Tags: json, gwt

The URL is
http://www.iwi.hs-karlsruhe.de/Intranetaccess/REST/courseofstudies/all.json

I can view the JSON file in my browser, but when I tried to get it in GWT, the result is empty. The alert in the following code is empty.

```
    RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, jsonURL);
    rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                Response response) {
            Window.alert(response.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
    rb.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is all about the same-origin policy.

Empty response text and a HTTP-code 0.

You cannot connect to that URL unless you are:

1. from the same origin
2. use JSONP
3. use CORS-Header

Comment: Thanks your are right. However, I am new to GWT and HTTP and whatsoever, I have no idea about any solution that you suggested. Anyway I know what to search now, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not about GWT in special. All Webapplication built with JavaScript have these limitations.